# Why does this method have no method print

Tags: javascript

I am sure this is really, really simple but why does the following not work.

```
var o = function() { };
o.prototype.print = function( ) { console.log("hi") };
o.print(); // console message: Object function o() { } has no method 'print'
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/ptDQS/1/)

**UPDATE**

Why does this also not work

```
var o = function() { };
o.prototype.print = function( ) { console.log("hi") };
var c = Object.create( o );
c.print();
```

I can start a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Question

> I am sure this is really, really simple but why does the following not work.

`o`  is a constructor for new objects, you have to create a new object in order to use prototype methods:

```
var x = new o();
x.print();
```

#### 2. Question

> Why does this also not work

Because `Object.create` takes a prototype and not an object:

```
var o = function() { };
o.prototype.print = function( ) { console.log("hi") };
var c = Object.create( o.prototype );
c.print();
```

See also

- MDN: [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
- MDN: [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [JSFiddle with the first example](http://jsfiddle.net/beQQz/)
- [JSFiddle with the second example](http://jsfiddle.net/ptDQS/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `o` as a constructor for an object. This object will inherit the prototype of `o`.

```
var o = function() { };
o.prototype.print = function( ) { console.log("hi") };
a = new o(); //a inherits prototype of constructor o
a.print();
```

Analogously, since `o` itself is an instance of `Function`, it inherits its prototype. Consider the fact that `var o = function(){}` can be desugared to:

```
var o = new Function (""); //o inherits prototype of constructor Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyObject(){ };
var o = new MyObject();
MyObject.prototype.print = function( ) { console.log("hi") };
o.print();
```